# wireless network security protocol

Tags: hmac, cbc-mac

In network security, encryption and integrity done by the same algorithm that is AES-CCM in that MIC generated by CBC-MAC and encryption done by CTR mode. So suppose I want to do encryption with any stream cipher algorithm, can I use some hashing mechanism like HMAC separately for integrity purposes?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and that's how it's normally done. This even applies to AEAD schemes like GCM, CCM, and EAX (which all encrypt with CTR and MAC as a separate matter with some other algorithm); with non-AEAD schemes, you have systems like CBC+HMAC in TLS, and (with stream ciphers for encryption) ChaCha20+Poly1305 (which are two completely independent algorithms). *However*, this is something that's *really* hard to get right, which is why standardized AEAD schemes are so nice (AEAD means there's a well-analyzed specification of *exactly* how to combine them).

Comment: thanks for reply..suppose i am doing encryption with some newest stream cipher algorithm then for integrity purpose some h-mac mechanism like SHA-1 to generate MIC.so how to show this type of demonstration??